# How to become Third-Party of AMP project?

Tags: amp-html

We developed an AMP extension like `amp-youtube` or `amp-vimeo` but it's for our specific product and we want to add it to `AMP CDN` and become a third-party of the AMP Project.
How can we submit our code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go visit the [AMP Github page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml), you will have to follow the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), and create a PR.

Also, [here's](https://www.ampproject.org/contribute/) an easy to follow guide on how to contribute to AMP.